# Keeping cmd cursor on same line after printing

Tags: python, windows, input, cmd

Im making a game that runs in command prompt and its supposed to take an input after being prompted. However, I need the cursor to remain on the same line as the prompt. Something like "Input next move: [cursor stays here]". im using msvcrt to get the input.

```
def getinput(game):
display(game)
inp = 21
print("Input next move: ")
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        inp = int(msvcrt.getch().decode("UTF-8"))
        while (inp > 8 or inp <0):
            print("Choose a number between 0 and 8")
            inp = int(msvcrt.getch().decode("UTF-8"))
        while (listgame[inp] != "."):
            print("Already occupied. Choose an available space")
            inp = int(msvcrt.getch().decode("UTF-8"))
        break
game[inp]=enemy
print("You played: " + str(inp))
```

Comment: Try using the `end=` option to the print function: `print('Choose a number between 0 and 8: ', end='\r', flush=True)`

Comment: @Ron Norris when I do print('input next move: ', end='\r', flush=True), the cursor remains on the line but is at the very beginning, highlighting the i in input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `end` option in your print statement to keep it from going to the next line, like this:

```
 print("Input next move: ", end="")
```

This will keep the cursor at the end of the line.